# My frist role have the id but the other no

Tags: php

### EDIT : My request have change and the id not working

It's creating a json format but only just the first role have the id, the others have nothing.

the first 4 line it's for debug.

I have one idea but i'm not sur

---

the first time :
$roles[0] = " | En sueur";

next i switch to the id so $roles[0] = "544556569212223489"

and the second time $roles[1] keep the first value.

If you want to try you go here --> [here](https://idrunk.xyz/discord/parserole?max=3&roles=%F0%9F%92%80%20%7C%20Cancer%2C%C2%A0%F0%9F%91%8C%20%7C%20Humoriste%2C%C2%A0%F0%9F%98%91%20%7C%20G%C3%AAnant)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4vuF.png)

### Code

```php
<?php 
$max = $_GET['max'];
$roles_list = $_GET['roles'];

if (!isset($roles_list) || !isset($max)) {
    echo "?max=x&roles=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
} else {
    $roles = explode(", ", $roles_list);
    $obj = new stdClass();

        for ($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++) {
            $name = "role_".($i +1);

            echo $roles[$i];

            if (strpos($roles[$i], "Tryharder") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556563361431567;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Alcoolique") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544572277019115528;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Tox") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556566435856394;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "En sueur") !== false) {

                $roles[$i] = 544556569212223489;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Tchatcheur") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556571880063012;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Gênant") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556574606360616;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Humoriste") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556577378795521;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Chanteur Officiel") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556579962486785;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Joueur RP") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556582973865984;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Raideur") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556585498837002;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Cancer") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556587994447874;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Otaku") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 608045490306678822;

            } else if (strpos($roles[$i], "Joueur FairPlay") !== false) {
                $roles[$i] = 544556591186444308;

            } else {
                $roles[$i] = 0;
            }


            $obj->$name = $roles[$i];
        }
    $json = json_encode($obj);
    echo $json;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work
**UPDATED**

```
$roles = explode(",", $roles_list);
```

in your get request you removed the %20 before every element which is space character

[image]

Comment: I have make some change because my request have change and now it's broken.

Comment: Hi i noticed you changed the code   that way you are checking  if the emoji name is exists  also you changed the way you send the request  if that html code in the request page will not change   then  you just   revert back to the this instead `$roles = explode(",", $roles_list);
`    update the answer

Comment: if that is what you want pls accept answer   , if there is anything you need i'm here to help